# Microsoft Office Add-in Store - Scheduling a release date in the future

Tags: ms-office, office-addins, office-store

I would like to set a release date in the future for a new version update of an already existing Microsoft Office Add-in app. In the docs here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/store/specify-availability it mentions that this is possible but when I look under Availability --> Schedule the date is greyed out and I am unable to change it.

Is it possible to schedule a release date in the future for a new version of an already existing Microsoft Office Add-in app?

Thanks!
Irina

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to alter the release date for an update to existing add-in as release controls availability on Microsoft AppSource, and changing the release date of an existing add-in would remove the existing add-in from Microsoft AppSource.